# Sub-Navigation extends regular nav and mis aligns

Tags: css

I am currently working on developing sub navigation bars that extend when hovered. However, whenever you hover on Manage, the regular box extends. (This is due to `position: relative` under `.bujar:hover .bujar-content`)

Whenever I change the position to absolute, it works fine.

But, if you resize the screen, on `position: relative` it works perfectly fine!
On `position: absolute`, it does not work on mobile.

Here is the CodePen version of the code:
https://codepen.io/bujars/pen/BgErzp

```css
.bujar:hover .bujar-content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  left: 100%;
  top: -35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav responsive" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">India<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Dashboard</a>

      <div class="bujar">
        <button class="bujar-dropbtn" style="
">Manage<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
        <div class="bujar-content" style="
       /* display: block; */
">


          <a href="#">Manage 1</a>
          <a href="#">Manage 2</a>
          <a href="#">Manage 3</a>
          <a href="#">Manage 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#">x</a>
      <a href="#">y</a>
      <a href="#">z</a>

      <div class="bujar">
        <button class="bujar-dropbtn" style="
       /* color: red; */
">Manage<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
        <div class="bujar-content" style="
       /* display: block; */
">


          <a href="#">Manage 1</a>
          <a href="#">Manage 2</a>
          <a href="#">Manage 3</a>
          <a href="#">Manage 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">G<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">D</a>
      <a href="#">S2</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by changing the position of `.bujar:hover .bujar-content` to `absolute`.

To make `position:absolute` work on smaller screen sizes, you will need to edit/ a few css classes in your code. Below are the classes that should be edited/added.

```
.bujar:hover .bujar-content 
 {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   left: 100%;
   top:-35px;
 }

@media screen and (max-width:600px)
{

 .topnav.responsive .bujar:hover .bujar-content
 {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
   /* top: 100%;*/  
   left: 5em;  
 }


  .topnav.responsive .bujar-content 
 {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    /* top: 100%;*/ 
    left: 0;

  }

 }
```

I also added css to better position the second nested dropdown.

```
  .bujar:hover .bujar-content.lower-me 
  {
     margin-top:8em;
  }
```

Of course you would have to add the `lower-me` class to the second nested dropdown div that has the `bujar-content`class.

Comment: Static doesn't allow you to go beyond the manage div. The scroll jumps right off. I tested it on the codepen link I attached

Comment: Indeed. That happened because when the pointer leaves the nested menu, the nested menu minimizes. This made the pointer stop hovering over the main dropdown menu, and thus the main dropdown menu collapsed. I edited my answer with a different approach to the problem.